# Simple join query giving ORA 00933 on Oracle8i Release 8.1.7.0.1

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle8i

Environment used -

```
Oracle8i Release 8.1.7.0.1
PL/SQL Release 8.1.7.0.0
TNS for Linux: Version 8.1.7.0.0
NLSRTL Version 3.4.1.0.0
```

Following simple query is giving me an error : ORA-00933:SQL command not properly ended

On SQL Developer 1.5.1 -

```
SELECT A.CLAIM_ID, B.SUBCLAIM_ID
FROM CLAIM3.TABLE_A  AS A
JOIN CLAIM3.TABLE_B AS B
ON A.CLAIM_ID = B.CLAIM_ID 
;
```

Comment: Going to assume you realize just how old your database and your SQL developer are...

Comment: Yes. The entire application suite is being upgraded to Oracle Database 12.1.0.2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle did not support the ANSI join syntax until version 9i.  Also, Huy Ngo is correct that Oracle does not allow `AS` for table aliases.  Try this code instead:

```
SELECT A.CLAIM_ID, B.SUBCLAIM_ID
  FROM CLAIM3.TABLE_A A, CLAIM3.TABLE_B B
 WHERE A.CLAIM_ID = B.CLAIM_ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your SQL query to this:

```
SELECT A.CLAIM_ID, B.SUBCLAIM_ID  
FROM CLAIM3.TABLE_A A  // No AS
JOIN CLAIM3.TABLE_B B  // No AS
ON A.CLAIM_ID = B.CLAIM_ID  
;
```

Comment: I have tried that. I have also tried not using the alias. Same error.

Comment: That was also not the case.

Comment: @OraAff I wonder if you have any sql query above your current select query. If yes, semicolon (or comment) them and try to execute again.